# Python ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: matplotlib, plot, error-handling

I'm getting this strange error on a longitude variable "lon" when calling "plt.figtext". I'm trying to plot the lon and lat on my plot like this example below in lower left corner. Suppose I have a longitude (lon) and latitude (lat) values extracted from a pandas df (dfn) that looks like this:

```
dfn.longitude
Out[122]: 
58    28.62354
59    28.62354

dfn.latitude
Out[123]: 
58    44.661127
59    44.661127
```

My lines of code leading up to the error row (plt.figtext...) look like this:

```
lon = round(dfn.longitude.tail(1),2)
lat = round(dfn.latitude.tail(1),2)
plt.figtext(0.05,0.00, lon, fontsize=8, va="top", ha="left")
```

The output of "lon" looks like this:

```
lon
Out[124]: 
86    28.62
Name: longitude, dtype: float64
```

And, the error is this:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or 
a.all().
```

I've seen this posted several places but cannot see how to change the values of lon and lat to correct the error. Thank you for any suggestions!

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJZD4.png
```

Comment: `DataFrame.tail`, is not a good way to access values. What do you see when you `print(lat, lon)`?

Comment: thanks, I changed the way i called the lat and lon and eliminated the use of .tail and that got rid of the error. Thank you!!